# How to create the flamingo ribbon menu?

Tags: java, swing

I'm using flamingo ribbon, but when i tried to put the menu, it didn't appear.

I used this code:

```
RibbonApplicationMenuEntryPrimary  menu1 = new RibbonApplicationMenuEntryPrimary(getResizableIconFromResource("/prog/Imagenes/Algo.png"), "Prueba 1", new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Menu secundario");
        }
    }, JCommandButton.CommandButtonKind.POPUP_ONLY);
    menu1.setActionKeyTip("P");
    menu1.setPopupKeyTip("W");

    RibbonApplicationMenuEntrySecondary menu2 = new RibbonApplicationMenuEntrySecondary(getResizableIconFromResource("/prog/imagenes/rs1.png"), "Prueba 2",null, JCommandButton.CommandButtonKind.POPUP_ONLY);
    menu2.setDescriptionText("seleccione algo");
    menu2.setActionKeyTip("P");

    RibbonApplicationMenuEntrySecondary menu3 = new RibbonApplicationMenuEntrySecondary(getResizableIconFromResource("/prog/imagenes/dp1.png"), "Prueba 3",null, JCommandButton.CommandButtonKind.ACTION_ONLY);
    menu3.setDescriptionText("algo");
    menu3.setActionKeyTip("Q");

    RibbonApplicationMenu menuPrinicpal = new RibbonApplicationMenu();
    RibbonApplicationMenuEntryPrimary salir = new RibbonApplicationMenuEntryPrimary(null, "Salir", new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dispose();
        }
    }, CommandButtonKind.ACTION_AND_POPUP_MAIN_ACTION);
    salir.setActionKeyTip("S");
    salir.setPopupKeyTip("X");

    menuPrinicpal.addMenuEntry(salir);
    cintaOmicronJRibbon.updateUI();

    menu1.addSecondaryMenuGroup("Compuesto", menu2,menu3);
    menuPrinicpal.addMenuEntry(menu1);
    menuPrinicpal.addMenuSeparator();


    cintaOmicronJRibbon.setApplicationMenu(menuPrinicpal);
    cintaOmicronJRibbon.updateUI();
```

Please help me thanks.

Comment: Do you add the menu to a frame anywhere?   You are not showing all the relevant code.

Comment: No, in a JRibbon class the menu is added to the JRibbon. The frame only contains the Jribbon component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, the code showed is wrong, I added a Jribbon as a property in my JRibbonFrame, but by default when a class inherits from a JRibbonFrame conatains the JRibbon element.

The code needs this.getRibbon() instead of cintaOmicronJRibbon.